# How to generate a range of numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, code-generation

Is there a quick and dirty way to generate a list of numbers from 1 to some arbitrary large number in order such that the digits of each number are only 0's, 1's, and 2's?

I tried doing

```
n = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2};
v = 
  Sort @ Rest @
    DeleteDuplicates[
      FromDigits /@ (Cases[
         Permutations /@ 
           Rest @ DeleteDuplicates @
             Subsets[n], {x__?(Head[#] =!= List &)} :> {x}, -1])];
```

but it slows down pretty fast, so I don't think I can add any more entries to `n`.

(Also, still not sure how to copy-paste *Mathematica* code in here so it looks exactly like it does in *Mathematica*)

Comment: See the [formatting guide](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help.  Copy/paste the regular `InputForm`, it looks like you copied `TeXForm` or `TraditionalForm` instead.

Comment: maybe `FromDigits /@ IntegerDigits[Range[1000], 3]`?

Comment: @kguler ... wow, your way is so much easier than what I was trying to do ...
 ***facepalm***
... Thanks, I feel silly.

Comment: @Solarmew I have that experience fairly regularly. :^)

Comment: @Solarmew, we all know the feeling:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possibly more general function to be aware of is [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html):

```
FromDigits /@ Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 4]
```

> {0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 100, 101, 102, 110, 111, 112, 120,
>   121, 122, 200, 201, 202, 210, 211, 212, 220, 221, 222, 1000, 1001,
>   1002, 1010, 1011, 1012, 1020, 1021, 1022,  1100, 1101, 1102, 1110,
>   1111, 1112, 1120, 1121, 1122, 1200, 1201, 1202, 1210, 1211, 1212,
>   1220, 1221, 1222, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2020, 2021,
>   2022, 2100, 2101, 2102, 2110, 2111, 2112, 2120, 2121, 2122, 2200,
>   2201, 2202, 2210, 2211, 2212, 2220, 2221, 2222}

This is a bit faster than using [`IntegerDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerDigits.html):

```
FromDigits /@ Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 12]              // Length // Timing
FromDigits /@ IntegerDigits[Range[0, 531440], 3] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.312002, 531441}
>
> {0.530403, 531441}
> ```

Comment: ouch ... "FromDigits /@ Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 12] " just definitely froze my laptop .... had to force restart again for the billionth time :( for some reason MemoryConstrained[ , (1524^3)] does nothing :(

Comment: @Solarmew That's strange.  What version of *Mathematica* are you running?  For me the `MaxMemoryUsed[]` after this command is `98783656` which should be within the limits of almost any device today.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll find this faster than either of the above:

```
f=FromDigits@Transpose@IntegerDigits[Range[0, #], 3, IntegerLength[#, 3]] &;
```

Use e.g.: `f@12345` is equalvlent to `FromDigits /@ IntegerDigits[Range[0, 12345], 3]` above.

Even faster:

```
FromDigits@Transpose@PadLeft@Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 11];
```

Comment: clever! +1 ----

Comment: @Mr.Wizard well thank you sir! Not sure of clever, I do find it a strange omission from the docs seeing as it's a useful form that's much faster than mapping... I use it often with bitmaps.