# Something wrong with FromDigits?

Tags: number-representation, prime-numbers

```
NestList[RotateLeft, IntegerDigits[19], 1]
FromDigits[%]
```

(* WRONG *)

```
NestList[RotateLeft, IntegerDigits[197], 2]
FromDigits[%]
```

OK

Looks like a bug in 10.2 under windows?
[image]

Or is it I misunderstood something when there are only two digits??
[image]

Comment: It's threading over the second sublist, e.g. `FromDigits[{{1, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]`. I'd use `FromDigits /@ {{1, 9}, {9, 1}}`.

Comment: `FromDigits` doesn't have the listable attribute so it doesn't automatically map over lists like some other functions do, which might be why it's confusing.

Comment: To expand on Ilian's comment, the form `FromDigits[{list, n}]` raises the number created from `list` to `n`, and in this case, when `n` is a list itself, e.g. `FromDigits[{{1, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}]`, you get `{19/10, 19, 19^2, 19^3}`.

Comment: By the way, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66484) is another example of the same issue.

Comment: @rcollyer I dont get where the 0 comes from n 19/10?

Comment: My apologies, that wasn't as clear as it could be. `FromDigits[{{a,b}, n}]` returns `10^(-2 + n) (10 a + b)` where `2` comes from the number of digits present in `{a,b}`. Does that help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in the comments this behavior follows from the definition of `FromDigits`, though I only understood this myself within the last year or two when someone* used it to boost performance.

Consider a symbolic example:

```
sym = FromDigits[{a, b, c}]

sym /. {
     a -> {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5},
     b -> {b1, b2, b2, b4, b5},
     c -> {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}
   }
```

> ```
> 10 (10 a + b) + c
>
> {10 (10 a1 + b1) + c1,
>  10 (10 a2 + b2) + c2,
>  10 (10 a3 + b2) + c3,
>  10 (10 a4 + b4) + c4, 
>  10 (10 a5 + b5) + c5}
> ```

Note that the evaluation of the expression `sym` threads over the substituted lists due to the properties of `Times`.  Therefore these operations are also equivalent in output:

```
FromDigits /@ {{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}, {a4, b4, c4}, {a5, b5, c5}}

FromDigits[{{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}, {b1, b2, b3, b4, b5}, {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5}}]
```

> ```
> {10 (10 a1 + b1) + c1,
>  10 (10 a2 + b2) + c2,
>  10 (10 a3 + b3) + c3,
>  10 (10 a4 + b4) + c4, 
>  10 (10 a5 + b5) + c5}
> ```

The performance of the two methods on long lists of short integers can be orders of magnitude apart however:

```
big = NestList[RotateLeft, IntegerDigits[12345], 5000];

(r1 = FromDigits /@ big)           // Length // RepeatedTiming
(r2 = FromDigits[big\[Transpose]]) // Length // RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> ```
> {0.0025, 5001}
>
> {0.0000953, 5001}
>
> True
> ```

* I thought it felt longer but I believe I am recalling this answer by rasher/ciao:

- [How to generate a range of numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77834/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers/77840#77840)

Comment: I don't see how you get from the intro to `FromDigits[big\[Transpose]]`, no matter how impressive that is. Would you elaborate?

Comment: @rcollyer I might be spewing nonsense; I apologize if that's the case.  I'll have to try to think this through again but I am becoming increasingly tired.

Comment: I blame the same thing on my lack of understanding. If you get to it, great. If not, oh well.

Comment: this makes perfect sense, take `10 (10 (10 a + b) + c) + d` , with each of the `a,b,c,d` being lists you get from `Transpose`.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. It must mean, I need more coffee.

Comment: and, as I look at it more, it is truly impressive. I can see where you'd get the speed boost. +1 (not that you need it)

Comment: @rcollyer [I keep trying...](http://imgur.com/gallery/uoKqLRm)

Comment: Why does this `(Thread[f[big]] /. f -> FromDigits)` work, but not `(Thread[FromDigits[big]] )`.  I keep reading the docs for `Thread` for the part where it says it behaves differently depending on the function.

Comment: @george2079 `Thread` doesn't hold its argument therefore you would need `Thread[Unevaluated @ FromDigits @ big]` I believe, or `FromDigits` will act first.

Comment: I figured that trick would go into your toolbox ;-)